# Proof of matrix norm inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I am having difficulties proving these norms, and I would like some help:

$\|A\|_2 \le \sqrt{n}\,\|A\|_{\infty}$

$\mathrm{cond}(A) \ge \|I\|$

$\|I\|=1$ (for an induced norm)

($A$ is a square matrix)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is ${\rm cond}(A)$? Is $A$ assumed to be invertible?

Comment: Condition Number. and yes, A is invertible